# How to prepare an Deployment Package properly for AWS lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, scrapy

I am doing a small project on python with scrapy. To upload it on AWS lambda , i simply created a folder,copied all the required libraries from my pc's site-packages , and deployed it on lambda ,which gave an error **UNABLE TO IMPORT ETREE** , i googled and found this solution [Unable to import lxml etree on aws lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818579/unable-to-import-lxml-etree-on-aws-lambda?answertab=active#tab-top) . I haven't used docker everr, all i want to know is After i have run a docker image of amazon linux on my pc, how do i install all the libraries in there,and then get those exported out to my pc,so i can upload it.

Answer (score 1):

You can install `docker` and run a simple `bash` script like this to create a layer

If you want to create a layer (and link to the lambda):

```
cd mylayer
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/var/task lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
zip -r ../my-layer.zip python
rm -rf python
cd -
```

If you want to create a lambda package:

```
cd mylambda
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/var/task lambci/lambda:build-python3.6 pip install -r requirements.txt --no-deps -t python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
zip -r ../my-lambda-package.zip python lambda_function.py
rm -rf python
cd -
```

Comment: I want to know that, when i run an amazonlinux image,then create a virtual environement, and then i pip install everything there, and then when i copy the directory out to my pc and deploy it online,it still gives the same errors.

Comment: @Kartiksharma what do you mean? did you try the script i suggested?

Comment: This looks promising but there is no support for python 3.9.  Any alternative?

Comment: You can use amazon linux docker images https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/available-runtimes.html or try with 3.8, some packages could be compatible across versions.