# AWS-Lambda Docker Image Error: "Error Message" : "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' "

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I am testing the aws-lambda function locally with my own input and the function runs perfectly, but when I attach the docker image to the function it quits with this import error. I have seen other questions about not finding the handler function, but I am successfully finding that.

Docker File:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8.2021.09.13.11

ADD lambda_function.py . 
ADD getEmail.py .
ADD site-packages . 

CMD ["lambda_function.handler"]
```

Error Json:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 
  'lambda_function': cannot import name 'etree' from 
  'lxml' (/var/task/lxml/__init__.py)"
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

lambda_function.py:

```
from logging import currentframe
import smtplib  
import email.utils
import json
from datetime import datetime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import time
import getEmail
from lxml.html.builder import S


name = ''


time = datetime.now()
def handler(event, context): 
    global name

    name = event['id']
    
    return event ['id']
    
    
    
def emailInfo(id, currentTime):
    SENDER = 
    SENDERNAME = 

# Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account 
# is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
    info = getEmail.get_email(id)
    print(info)
    RECIPIENT  = info['Email']
    

# Replace smtp_username with your Amazon SES SMTP user name.
    USERNAME_SMTP = 

# Replace smtp_password with your Amazon SES SMTP password.
    PASSWORD_SMTP = 

# (Optional) the name of a configuration set to use for this message.
# If you comment out this line, you also need to remove or comment out
# the "X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET:" header below.
#CONFIGURATION_SET = "ConfigSet"

# If you're using Amazon SES in an AWS Region other than US West (Oregon), 
# replace email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com with the Amazon SES SMTP  
# endpoint in the appropriate region.
    HOST = "email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
    PORT = 587

# The subject line of the email.
    SUBJECT = ''

# The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
    BODY_TEXT = """""
    """"".format(id, currentTime)

# The HTML body of the email.
    BODY_HTML = """<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
 </p>
</body>
</html>
            """.format(id, currentTime)

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
    msg['From'] = email.utils.formataddr((SENDERNAME, SENDER))
    msg['To'] = RECIPIENT
# Comment or delete the next line if you are not using a configuration set
#msg.add_header('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET',CONFIGURATION_SET)

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    part1 = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(BODY_HTML, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
    msg.attach(part1)
    msg.attach(part2)

# Try to send the message.
    try:  
        server = smtplib.SMTP(HOST, PORT)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
    #stmplib docs recommend calling ehlo() before & after starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(USERNAME_SMTP, PASSWORD_SMTP)
        server.sendmail(SENDER, RECIPIENT, msg.as_string())
        server.close()
# Display an error message if something goes wrong.
    except Exception as e:
       print ("Error: ", e)
    else:
        print ("Email sent!")

emailInfo(name ,time)
```

Comment: What is your `lambda_function.py`?

Comment: Where do you install `lxml` and all other dependencies?

Comment: @Marcin, this is my first time working with a lambda function from a docker image, but I believe it should be covered by the `ADD site-packages .`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import lxml etree on aws lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818579/unable-to-import-lxml-etree-on-aws-lambda)

Comment: Yes, it does! thank you @MetroSmurf

Comment: Also see https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/s2gnnt/awslambda_docker_image_error_error_message_unable/ ?